# ajax login error, can't check

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have problem, I can't check `username` and `password`, can you help me?

**login.php:**

```
<form class="login-form" method="post" name="loginform" action="">
    <div class="title-section">
        <h1><span>Login</span></h1>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome! Login in to your account</p>
    <label for="user_login">Username or email address<span>*</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login">
    <label for="user_pass">Password<span>*</span>
    </label>
    <input name="pwd" id="user_pass" type="password">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit-login" id="submit-login"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> Login </button>
</form>
```

**model.php;**

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start(); 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
?>
<?php
global $pdo;
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit-login'])) {
    $user_email = trim($_POST['log']);
    $user_password = trim($_POST['pwd']);

    try { 
        global $pdo;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=:email");
        $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$user_email));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($row['user_password']==$password){
            echo "ok"; // log in
            echo $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['id_user'];
        }
        else {
            echo "email or password does not exist."; // wrong details 
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-login").click(function(){
        username=$("#user_login").val();
        password=$("#user_pass").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/module/admin/model/acc_model.php",
            data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
            success: function(html){    
                if(html=='ok') {
                    window.location="profile.php";
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please, Error');
                }
            },
            beforeSend:function() {
                $("#error").html("<img src='http://www.chinesecio.com/templates/base/images/loading.gif' /> Loading...")
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Add more details on what you're trying to achieve and exactly what problems you're facing. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Wrong parameters I think `name="+username+"&pwd`. `$user_email = trim($_POST['log']);` This `submit-login` also isn't set so you never enter conditional.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the data like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit-login").click(function(){
    username=$("#user_login").val();
    password=$("#user_pass").val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/module/admin/model/acc_model.php",
            data: {
                name : username,
                pwd  : password
            },
            success: function(html){    
                if(html=='ok')    {
                    window.location="profile.php";
                }
                else    {
                  alert('Please, Error');
                }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                $("#error").html("<img src='http://www.chinesecio.com/templates/base/images/loading.gif' /> Loading...")
            }
          });
          return false;
  });
});
```

Also use parameter like below :

```
$user_email = trim($_POST['name']);
$user_password = trim($_POST['pwd']);
```

Comment: i edited code, but that still show line alert('Please, Error');

Comment: @BiHíp are you ignore comments on your question?

Comment: :'( i'm so sorry @chris85 because i don't reply comments of you, i have code t code accord you wirte :)

Comment: @BiHíp I don't know what that means, update your question if you re-wrote code. Address the comments in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you are sending data from your ajax request you are using different variable names and in your model.php you are using your form elements name. Please check into that

```
data : {"name":username, "password ":password}
```